# How do I set the content type in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm just trying to setup a very simple controller to return a very simple view (with a very simple layout), however I keep getting errors related to the content type.

```
class SimpleController {
    def index() {
        render(view: "simple")
    }
 }
```

_simple.gsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="blank" />
</head>
<body>
Simple test page.
</body>
</html>
```

blank.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <g:layoutHead />
</head>
<body>
    <g:layoutBody />
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't get much simpler than that.  The controller method is found correctly, the issue seems to be during the rendering.  Here's the error I'm getting:

2016-07-05 16:07:14,931 [http-bio-8085-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /testApp/simple/
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   15 |                           in com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.HttpContentType

---

|     49 | build                           in com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.PageParser2ContentProcessor
|     89 | getContent . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsContentBufferingResponse
|    107 | obtainContent                   in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutView

Debugging confirms that context.contentType is null.  I've found four different way to set the content type, but none of them seem to work.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

At the top of the view.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In the head tag of the view.

```
contentType: "text/html"
```

Passed to the render method in the controller.

```
response.setContentType("text/html")
```

Called in the controller method.

This is in an existing project, where many other controllers and views work perfectly fine.  I need to add a new controller and view, which I originally copied existing working pieces.  When that didn't work, I tried to reduce the problem down to be as simple as possible, and ended up with the above code, which is still not working.

Btw, this is with Grails 2.5.1 (stuck with this version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there should work.

If you're using the default URL mappings you should name your view *simple.gsp* instead of *_simple.gsp*

If it's not as simple as that you might try recreating a simple app.

Comment: Thanks.  I can never figure out with grails when the _ is needed or not.  The code I copied from uses an _ and I just went with it.  I didn't even think of changing it since the view resolver didn't throw an error about not being able to find the specified view.

Answer (score 1):

Could be even simpler and incidentally solve your problem.

```
class SimpleController {
    def index() {

    }
}
```

Rename _simple.gsp to index.gsp and needs to be located in views/simple/ directory. If blank.gsp its in views/layouts directory it should work now.

Comment: Both of these answers worked, but for my purposes jmallen's answer is a better match.

Answer (score 0):

As @jmallen said, the page should be named "simple.gsp".
The underscore at the beginning is something I only know for templates, gsp-files, that could be included in other pages with the following statement:

```
<g:render template="/layouts/menu" />
```

than the gsp file for the menu is named

```
_menu.gsp
```